# Testing event-driven tcp applications

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, tcp, nunit

I have written an event-driven tcp server for specific needs of a system we develop in my work place. I have also written unit-tests for that.
I have used standard C# TcpListener and TcpClient to connect to my library in each test. I am writing specific bits of data into them and then checking if appropriate events have been fired by the tested code.
The problem is - it is a race! I mean, sometimes when I write data to the TcpClient, and event might be fired immediately, sometimes it might take 100ms, sometimes if the computer is slow (or connection is slow) it will take more.
This said, let's draw a simple test (I am using NUnit btw):

```
[Test]
public void TestEventA()
{
    bool eventFired = false;

    //my server would listen on 127.0.0.1:9090
    MyTcpServer serv = new MyTcpServer("127.0.0.1", 9090);
    serv.OnA += new AEventHandler((object sender, AEventArgs args) =>
    {
        eventFired = true;
    });

    //imitating a remote client connecting
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9090);

    //remote client is sending data
    client.Getstream().Write(/*you know the drill here*/);

    //give the connection and server time to react
    System.Threading.Sleep(100);

    Assert.IsTrue(eventFired);
}
```

So this is just a simple example of a test. The thing is - it passes every time on my local PC, but on our build server it is completely random. Now I am 100% sure it is because the event wasn't fired yet when we get to the assert. The problem is, I don't know how to properly design the test to avoid that race conditions.
I am sure that many of you did similar things (maybe not with TCP, but with testing event-driven stuff, when we don't know how long it will take for the event to fire etc), so I would love to learn from your experiences.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an end to end/integration test, in this kind of scenario what else can you do besides increase the sleep time?

If you want to unit test the server you will need to write it in a way where you can mock a connection from a client, so you wouldn't need to actually instantiate a network connection.

Comment: Even then, if there is alot of processing happening before an event is fired, you still can't predict how long you should sleep to make sure that event will be fired by the time you get to an assert. So I was hoping for a different approach to the test-design to avoid running into situations like that.

Comment: If you unit test the server - where all connections to network/db etc are mocked, you won't have this problem. In an end2end test I don't think you can get away from it

Comment: Yes I understand, the network connection can cause a delay. But imagine the situation like that: you mocked the connection, you send the data, the server is processing it for say 500ms (some CPU heavy operations) before it is ready to fire the event, but you wait only for 300ms. So you increase the wait to 600ms, but then on slower machine with less CPU power the processing will take 1000ms... do you see the problem here? Not only TCP delay is a problem, but the gap between "I got the data" and "I am ready to fire an event" is an issue too in the event-driven apps...